# The page margin and the start of the paragraph are not match in ITextsharp

Tags: itext

I am using Itextsharp.

```
doc.SetMargins(36, 36, 36, 36);
doc.NewPage();
writer.PageEvent = new PDFPageEvent();

int horizontalMarginForColumn = 54;
int bottomMarginForColumn = 72;
int topMarginForColumn = 112;
int interval = 8;

Rectangle pageNumberLeftLocation = new Rectangle(horizontalMarginForColumn, doc.PageSize.Height - 36, horizontalMarginForColumn + 36, doc.PageSize.Height);

paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.SpacingBefore = 0;
paragraph.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
line = new LineSeparator(1f, 100f, BaseColor.BLACK, 0, 0f);
line.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
paragraph.Add(new Chunk(line));
paragraph.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
chunk = new Chunk("                    Index", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 15, Font.BOLD));
chunk.setLineHeight(23);
paragraph.Add(chunk);
paragraph.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
paragraph.Add(new Chunk(line));
doc.Add(paragraph);

writer.DirectContent.SetColorStroke(BaseColor.BLUE);
writer.DirectContent.Rectangle(pageNumberLeftLocation.Left, pageNumberLeftLocation.Bottom, pageNumberLeftLocation.Width, pageNumberLeftLocation.Height);
writer.DirectContent.Stroke();
```

The top margin of the page is 36, and the height of the rectangle is 36. So I assume that the bottom line of the rectangle and the beginning of the paragraph which is a black line, sholud be in the same vertical position. But you can see, there is some space between the two. Why is this? Thank you.

Comment: I think you are overlooking the concept of the `leading`, but it's unclear to give you a more conclusive answer because there is code missing in your example (no `doc.Open()`) and there is irrelevant code (the `ColumnText` part). Your question is unclear. An image illustrating the problem would improve the question.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Yes, you are right. I overlook the Leading. Thank you very much.